# How to change/disable SSH message on connect?

Tags: ssh

I have a Linux server with `SSH` service on it. If I performing a `TCP` connection to it (e.g. `telnet %ip% %port%`), it sends me a version line, like `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3`. It is not a `banner`! (Banner sent after successful authentication).
So, my question: it is possible to disable this message or change it?
Without recompiling from source code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to change that as it is part of the Protocol Version Exchange defined [RFC 4253](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt) and as such is necessary to establishing an ssh connection.

See Section 4.2

> When the connection has been established, both sides MUST send an
>      identification string.  This identification string MUST be
>
> SSH-protoversion-softwareversion SP comments CR LF
>
> ```
>   ...
> ```

Comment: So, it couldn't be empty or something like `Hey there!`?

Comment: `Hey there` would not appear to be a valid SSH Protocol version.